# How to make server component reflect data changes, made with server actions?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13, react-server-components

I have a server component `ChatList`, that fetches data from the database and displays it:

```js
// server component

import Link from "next/link";
import db from "@/prisma";

export const ChatList = async () => {
  const chats = await db.chat.findMany();

  return (
    <ul>
      {chats.map((chat) => (
        <li key={chat.id}>
          <Link href={`chat/${chat.id}`}>{chat.name}</Link>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

Then I have a [server action](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions), that creates new record in the same table:

```js
"use server";

import db from "@/prisma";

export const createChat = async (name: string) => {
  const newChat = await db.chat.create({
    data: { name },
  });
  return newChat;
};
```

This action is being invoked as form [`action` prop](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions#action).

Once new record is created, how do I tell the server component `ChatList` to refetch the data?

Comment: How and where is this action invoked? Also, do you know this is, as of now an alpha, not a stable feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this by calling `router.refresh()` in your form action.

```
"use client";

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

// ...

const router = useRouter();

// ...

<form
  action={async (formData) => {
    const name = formData.get("name");
    if (typeof name === "string") {
      await createChat(name);
      router.refresh();
    }
  }}
>
```

You can also look into experimental [useOptimistic](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions#experimental-useoptimistic) hook to make the UI look more responsive.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by applying polling where your react component keep sending request and looking for any update after some intervals of time. In react you can achieve that using useState and useEffect.

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import db from "@/prisma";

export const ChatList = async () => {
  const [chats, setChats] = useState([]);

  const fetchChats = async () => {
    const updatedChats = await db.chat.findMany();
    setChats(updatedChats);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchChats();

    const pollingInterval = setInterval(fetchChats, 5000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(pollingInterval);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <ul>
      {chats.map((chat) => (
        <li key={chat.id}>
          <Link href={`chat/${chat.id}`}>{chat.name}</Link>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

Another way of doing is using long-polling that will keep the request open.

Comment: 1) It would be a pretty bad idea to expose db credentials to the client (I’m not even sure that Prisma would even work on the client); 2) It would be pretty wasteful to poll at fixed intervals unless the OP really intends to do so; 3) Long polling is not something that Next.js/Vercel really supports.